# Remove values selected in ng-select from outside

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I have used `ng-select` to select multiple values from a list. As per requirement, the selected values should be shown below the `ng-select` component, and it must be possible to remove the filter from below.

The code can be found here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gm6zrs?file=src/multi-select-default-example.component.ts

When I try to remove using the Remove button, though the item gets removed from `ngModel - selectedPeople` here, it is not reflected in `ng-select`.

Comment: Please include the relevant code directly in your post. Links tend to die, and without the link your question would not be useful to anyone reading it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Try add this code inside `removeItem` function

```
this.selectedPeople = [...this.selectedPeople];
```

I've tried and it works, I also found this somewhere I forgot where it was so I can't give you an explanation

Comment: The explanation is that ng-select is using OnPush change detection and OnPush works by comparing references of the inputs. Removing the item using the splice function doesn't change the array reference. Adding the line above creates a new array and changes the reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` like that:

```
removeItem(idx) {
    this.selectedPeople = this.selectedPeople.filter(t => t.name !== idx.name);
    console.log(this.selectedPeople);
  }
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gm6zrs-h32qxt?file=src/multi-select-default-example.component.ts) is working sample.